# Copy column to another table, but keep equal ID's

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've searched all over, but can't find an answer to this.. I have two tables `user_setting` and `fibruser` which both contains ID's to users. `fibruser` contains all possible ID's, but `user_setting` only contain a few. I need to copy all `fibruser.id` to `user_setting.user_id` where `user_id` is `NULL` and make sure none of the existing ones get overridden.

I do this Query:

```
SELECT user_setting.user_id, fibruser.id
    FROM user_setting
    FULL JOIN fibruser 
    ON user_id = fibruser.id;
```

[image]

to compare ID's and find all the ID's, but I simply cannot get `UPDATE user_setting` working like I want to...

```
UPDATE user_setting
    SET user_id = fibruser.id
    FROM fibruser
    WHERE user_id IS null;
```

This only gives me `UPDATE user_setting
SET user_id = fibruser.id
FROM fibruser
WHERE user_id = id
AND user_id IS null;

This only outputs `0 row(s) affected`.. What am I doing wrong and/or missing?

**EDIT:** Forgot to mention datatypes. 
`id: INT(auto increment)` 
`user_id: INT`

Comment: First imagine a user_setting row, picked at random. Now, how do you know *which* fibruser.id its user_id should be set to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do a FULL JOIN, all those null values you are seeing represent cases where there **is** a row in fibruser with the given ID value, but there is **NOT** any row with that ID value in user_setting. Thus, when you do an UPDATE on user_setting, by definition you are going to have 0 rows affected; you have specifically told it to only update rows that you know do not exist!

What I think you want to do is to INSERT those rows, something like this:

```
INSERT INTO user_setting (user_id)
SELECT f.id
FROM fibruser f
WHERE f.id NOT IN (SELECT user_id FROM user_setting);
```

Alternatively, you could write it with NOT EXISTS:

```
INSERT INTO user_setting (user_id)
SELECT f.id
FROM fibruser f
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM user_setting u WHERE f.id = u.user_id);
```

You may find that one way or the other will run faster, or they may be identical; however, since I'm assuming you're only doing this one time, you probably don't care too much about performance, so you can just pick whichever syntax floats your boat.

Comment: The `IN` solution would need to be amended by adding a condition to the subquery: `WHERE user_id IS NOT NULL`. Otherwise, the existing NULLs in `user_id` would cause an empty output.